# Python: Create Dictionary using list of list, list of tuples and list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list `l1` as shown below:

```
l1 = [[(1,"INC1"), (1, "INC2")],[(3, "INC4"),(4, "INC6")]]
```

I have a list `names` as shown below:

```
names = ['John', 'Marcia']
```

I have another list `label_issue_list` as shown below:

```
label_issue_list = [["Problem1","Problem1"],["Problem3","Problem4"]]
```

The indices of all the three lists are connected as shown in the below output.

I'm trying to use all these three lists and get a dictionary output which would like the below:

```
{
"John" : {
            "Problem1" : 2,
          "tick_info" : {"1": ["INC1", "INC2"]}

            },
"Marcia" : {
            "Problem3" : 1,
            "Problem4" : 1,
            "tick_info" : {"3":["INC4"], "4":["INC6"]}
           }
}
```

I have tried the below code but this doesn't seem to work:

```
clust_stack = {}
for i in range(len(l1)):
      fq= defaultdict( list )
      for n,v in l1[i]:
           fq[str(n)].append(v)
      for name_, data in zip(names, label_issue_list)[i]:
           clust_stack[name_] = Counter(map(str,data))
           clust_stack[name_]["tick_info"] = {}
           clust_stack[name_]["tick_info"] = dict(fq)
```

I get the below error in the `for name_, data in zip(names, label_issue_list)[i]:` line:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

What do I need to do to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with zipping all 3 lists:

```
clust_stack = {}
for name, data, fq in zip(names, label_issue_list, l1):
    clust_stack[name] = dict(Counter(data))  # turn back into regular dictionary
    tick_info = clust_stack[name]['tick_info'] = {}
    for num, tick in fq:
        tick_info.setdefault(num, []).append(tick)
```

Using a `Counter` to count the information in each `l1` element is excellent, but you do need to turn that result back to a regular dictionary so you can add other keys to it.

You can then add the `tick_info` key to that, collecting the information in those lists in list values per key.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> l1 = [[(1,"INC1"), (1, "INC2")],[(3, "INC4"),(4, "INC6")]]
>>> names = ['John', 'Marcia']
>>> label_issue_list = [["Problem1","Problem1"],["Problem3","Problem4"]]
>>> clust_stack = {}
>>> for name, data, fq in zip(names, label_issue_list, l1):
...     clust_stack[name] = dict(Counter(data))  # turn back into regular dictionary
...     tick_info = clust_stack[name]['tick_info'] = {}
...     for num, tick in fq:
...         tick_info.setdefault(num, []).append(tick)
... 
>>> pprint(clust_stack)
{'John': {'Problem1': 2, 'tick_info': {1: ['INC1', 'INC2']}},
 'Marcia': {'Problem3': 1,
            'Problem4': 1,
            'tick_info': {3: ['INC4'], 4: ['INC6']}}}
```